# Restoring 'TopMost' window behavior after 'full screen mode' has ended (.NET)

Tags: .net, fullscreen, z-order, topmost

I have a (Windows Forms) application that consists of a single window with the "TopMost" property set. If an application (e.g. PowerPoint) temporarily enters full screen mode the "TopMost" behavior of my window is not restored (i.e. it will remain hidden the maximized PowerPoint window). Interestingly, this only happens when my application is started BEFORE the other application -- if the other application is started prior to mine things works as expected. Activating the window (manually clicking on it) restores the desired behavior but this is unfortunately not a solution for me.

I am unsure what causes this problem and I would be very interested in fix or a workaround.

Since this may be an OS related issue I should point out that I am using Windows 7 64-bit.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: When "temporarily enters full screen mode", do you mean while playing a slide show in PowerPoint? Because obviously you would want the slide show to play full screen. Your application is not going to automatically rearrange itself in the Z order once you close PowerPoint. As you mention, clicking on it brings it back to the front and everything goes as normal. This is the expected behavior.

Comment: When I hit escape i a full screen PowerPoint slideshow presentation then my window is hidden behind the PowerPoint window (that is not longer fullscreen but simply maximized).

Comment: I think there can be only a single 'topmost' form (or window) system-wise, i bet powerpoint also sets itself as topmost when it goes full-screen.

Comment: It looks like it's a reasonably well known problem, and has existed across multiple windows versions: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7desktop/thread/369dc23a-21b3-4f92-be2d-c5afc869117b

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the topmost property to: `false`
Then back to: `true`
This should override ppts topmost property.
You can repeat this every few seconds in your program using the `Timer` class